# if(a = 1) is true

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I don't know if it's possible duplicate. Testing my code, sometimes I was wrong with because I put `=` and not `==` or `===` in if conditions:

Consider this code :

```
var a = 0;
if(a = 1) console.log('true');
```

I don't know why this is not an error and why returns true the condition (a = 1)
I guess that what it does is assign `1` to the `a` variable, but why this evaluates to true and there's no error?

Comment: `a = 1` asignes `1` to `a`, then the result of this expression (`1`) is evaluated as the condition and `1` is  a truthy value.

Comment: The answers have conveyed why this is happening.  I just wanted to point out this is why WordPress and Symfony coding standards insist on [yoda conditions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). By reversing the normal order of things in the condition, you create situations that throw errors. In your example, using `1 = a` instead of `a = 1` *would trigger* an error because you can't assign a value to a literal number. But there are a lot of developers out there who don't like yoda conditions because they can make the code harder to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're setting a to 1 and then checking the truthiness of the result.  Non-zero numbers in JavaScript are true, so you get what you see.

Like in math, things are evaluated left-to-right, with parens going first.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said, it does assign to your variable and will return true for all values other than 0.

A way to avoid these kind of mistakes is to change the test.

```
if( 3 == a)
```

Here if you ever write `(3 = a)` you would have an error.

Comment: `will return true for all values other than 0`, that is not correct: `false`, `''`(empty string), `undefined`, `NaN` are also values that are falsy

Comment: I guess he wanted to say numbers!

Comment: That's correct, I thought about it for a second when I was writing my answer but never came back to correct it. I'll fix it.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! I have now the things clear!